# How to make tooltip with pure Javascript (onclick show/dismiss)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, tooltip

I need to use some JS no JQuery plugins to make a simple tooltip.

When I click on image I want to display div with triangle corner below that image with some text inside.

I Google and Google and didn't find anything.

Simple click on image to show info and click on same image to dismiss it but can't figure out how to do this.

[image]

Comment: As a triangle? In the corner?

Comment: Do you not want to use a premade jquery plugin or do you not want to use jquery at all?

Comment: @some yes square image 40x40px and when I click on it to display bellow it a div with triangle in the top right corner just bellow the image.

Comment: @user2938649 no jquery

Comment: If you look at the answer/jsfiddle you'll see that the jquery needed is very minimal. Might be worth checking out instead of pure JS.

Comment: @user2938649 jquery is good but [not the answer to everything](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/20091116-so-large.gif). The poster asked specifically for a pure javascript solution. I don't know the reason in this case, but it is quite educational to do it without jquery, and it can be much clearer and understandable code without it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're willing to use jquery, but not a plugin, then this can be done pretty simply.

http://jsfiddle.net/GQE4k/

```
var h = false;
$("#container").hover(function(){
    if (h == false){
        $("#popUp").fadeIn();
        $("#popUpText").fadeIn();
        h = true;
    }
},function(){
    if (h == true){
        $("#popUp").fadeOut();
        $("#popUpText").fadeOut(function(){h=false});
    }
});
```

For click instead of hover:

http://jsfiddle.net/GQE4k/1/

```
var h = false;
$("#container").click(function(){
    if (h == false){
        $("#popUp").fadeIn();
        $("#popUpText").fadeIn(function(){h = true;});
    }
    if (h == true){
        $("#popUp").fadeOut();
        $("#popUpText").fadeOut(function(){h=false});
    }
});
```

Comment: No, sorry maybe I was not said right what I want to do. I have added an image of an example.

Comment: @1110 that is far from what you wrote first. It'd be very kind, if you accepted user2938649's answer, and open a new question.

Comment: Ok I'll do it sorry I wasn't clear enough

Comment: I put it here if you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154572/how-to-make-this-tooltip-like-this-with-pure-javascript

Comment: @Kay So 1110 specifically asked for a pure javascript solution without jquery, and you ask him to accept an answer that uses jquery? I admit that the query was unclear, but that is whats comments are for, to get a clarification. However it was clear form the start that 1110 wanted a pure javascript, non jquery solution.