# How to make this tooltip like this with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, tooltip

I need to use JS no JQuery plugins to make a simple tooltip like on the image below.

Click on <kbd>?</kbd> image should open this tooltip and click again on the same image to close it.
I think that it's simple for someone with good JS knowledge but I can't do it anyway :(

This is something that I have tried I know it's not too much but I am simply stuck.
How to display it like on the image, how to hide it when it's open and how to add that little triangle in the corner?

[myfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D7UKX/)

```
<img id="info" src="http://www.craiglotter.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/craig_question_mark_icon1.png"/>
<div id="ttip">bla bla</div>

document.getElementById('info').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // how to check if it's visible so I can close tooltip
    document.getElementById('ttip').style.display="block";    
});

#info{margin-left:100px;margin-top:50px;}
#ttip
{
    width: 280px;
z-index: 15001;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
display: none;
    border-color: #666;
background-color: #fff;
color: #666;
    position: relative;
border: 1px solid #666;
padding: 15px 9px 5px 9px;
text-align: left;
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to explain your base of knowledge, which parts of this you know how to do, what you've found when you searched and which part of this problem you specifically need help with.  In other words, you need to show you've at least put some base level of effort into getting started here and then show us where you got stuck.

Comment: I have tried with JQuery plugins and thats not good as I need pure JavaScript. I have tried some stuff but didn't get with anything really. I know just to show div on click but not to show it like this with arrow point to image that was clicked. So I don't have anything that is similar to this :(

Comment: I am shamed. I updated question I know it;s not too much but can't make what I want. I work very little with js.

Comment: @1110  this should do the trick now: http://jsfiddle.net/u93a3/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean up the css and this will basically do it:

```
<script>
    function doTip(e){
          var elem = e.toElement;
          if(elem.getAttribute('data-tip-on')  === 'false') {

            elem.setAttribute('data-tip-on', 'true');
            var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();          
            var tipId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
            elem.setAttribute('data-tip-id', tipId);
            var tip = document.createElement("div");
            tip.setAttribute('id', tipId);
            tip.innerHTML = elem.getAttribute('data-tip');
            tip.style.top = rect.bottom+ 10 + 'px';
            tip.style.left = (rect.left-200) + 'px';
            tip.setAttribute('class','tip-box');
            document.body.appendChild(tip);

          } else {

            elem.setAttribute('data-tip-on', 'false');
            var tip = document.getElementById(elem.getAttribute('data-tip-id'));
            tip.parentNode.removeChild(tip);


          }
    }
    function enableTips(){
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('quick-tip');
        for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) { 
            elems[0].addEventListener("click", doTip, false);

        }
    }
    window.onload = function(){
        enableTips();
    }
</script>
<style>
    .quick-tip {
        background: black;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 900;
        margin-left: 350px;

    }
    .tip-box {
    /* change dimensions to be whatever the background image is */
        height: 50px;
        width: 200px;
        background: grey;
        border: 1px solid black; 
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>


<div class="quick-tip" data-tip="THIS IS THE TIP! change elements 'data-tip' to change." data-tip-on="false">?</div>

<script>enableTips(); //might be required for jsfiddle, especially with reloads.</script>
```

Edit: fixed formatting and a bug. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u93a3/

Comment: window.onload won't fire all the time in jsfiddle. Add this to the bottom of the html to ensure it will: 

`<script>enableTips();</script>`

Comment: here's the fiddle with the correct background for the tip: http://jsfiddle.net/u93a3/1/

Comment: Ahh thanks I was just trying to change your code to add that triangle. Thanks. I will learn a lot from this code. Thanks again.

Comment: I will just try to extend this to not use image as a background but to add that right corner triangle with css somehow.

Comment: The only thing is that this too doesn't work in IE it seams that IE doesn't recognize addEventListener...

Answer (score 2):

Proof of concept:

The following markup in HTML: Create a div with class `tooltip`, add image and a div with class `info` with all text (can be multiple paragraphs if needed, scollbars is shown if necessary):

```
<div class='tooltip'>
  <img src='craig_question_mark_icon1.png' alt='Help'/>
  <div class='info'>
    Some text to fill the box with.
  </div>
</div>
```

The `div.info` is set to `display:none` in CSS.

When the page is loaded a pure javascript is running that draws an image of a triangle on a canvas-element, and then creates a div-element where the triangle is set as a background. Then, for every `div.tooltip`:

1. add a click-eventhandler to the image
2. replace the `div.info` with a `div.info_container`
3. add a clone of the triangle-div to `div.info_container`
4. add the original `div.info` to `div.info_container`

You can test it with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/some/66nLy/). It is tested successfully on FF25, Chrome31, IE10, Opera 12&18.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      "use strict";
      function click(event) {
        var elem = this.parentNode.querySelector('div.info_container');
        if (elem) elem.style.display = elem.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
      }
      function toolify() {
        var idx,
            len,
            elem,
            info,
            text,
            elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.tooltip'),
            canvas,
            imgurl,
            pointer,
            tipHeight = 20,
            tipWidth = 20,
            width = 200,
            height = 100,
            ctx;

        // Create a canvas element where the triangle will be drawn
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = tipHeight;
        canvas.height = tipWidth;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';   // Border color
        ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';     // background color
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;

        ctx.translate(-0.5,-0.5);   // Move half pixel to make sharp lines
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(1,canvas.height);              // lower left corner
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, 1);              // upper right corner
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,canvas.height);   // lower right corner
        ctx.fill();                               // fill the background
        ctx.stroke();                             // stroke it with border
        //fix bottom row
        ctx.fillRect(0,canvas.height-0.5,canvas.width-1,canvas.height+2);

        // Create a div element where the triangel will be set as background
        pointer = document.createElement('div');
        pointer.style.width = canvas.width + 'px';
        pointer.style.height = canvas.height + 'px';
        pointer.innerHTML = '&nbsp;' // non breaking space
        pointer.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + canvas.toDataURL() + ')';
        pointer.style.position = 'absolute';
        pointer.style.top = '2px';
        pointer.style.right = '1px';
        pointer.style.zIndex = '1'; // place it over the other elements

        for (idx=0, len=elements.length; idx < len; ++idx) {
          elem = elements[idx];
          elem.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click',click);
          text = elem.querySelector('div.info');
          // Create a new div element, and place the text and pointer in it
          info = document.createElement('div');
          text.parentNode.replaceChild(info,text);
          info.className = 'info_container';
          info.appendChild(pointer.cloneNode());
          info.appendChild(text);
          //info.addEventListener('click',click);
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load',toolify);
    </script>
    <style>
      div.tooltip
      {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        width:300px;
        text-align:right;
      }
      div.tooltip > div.info
      {
        display:none;
      }
      div.tooltip div.info_container
      {
        position:absolute;
        right:20px;
        width:200px;
        height:100px;
        display:none;
      }
      div.tooltip div.info
      {
        text-align:left;
        position:absolute;
        left:1px;
        right:1px;
        top:20px;
        bottom:1px;
        color:#000;
        padding:5px;
        overflow:auto;
        border:1px solid #000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='tooltip'>
      <img src='craig_question_mark_icon1.png' alt='Help'/>
      <div class='info'>
        Some text to fill the box with.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='tooltip'>
      <img src='craig_question_mark_icon1.png' alt='Help'/>
      <div class='info'>
        Some text to fill the box with.
        Some text to fill the box with.
        Some text to fill the box with.
        Some text to fill the box with.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only thing is that this doesn't work in IE it seams that IE doesn't recognize addEventListener...

Comment: @1110 What version are you running? It has been [supported since IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Older versions used [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (attachEvent is unsupported in IE11)