# How can I extend this JavaScript to work for more than one item?

Tags: javascript, html

I found a solution which allows me to click on an area to display a tool tip using JavaScript, but only works for the first item. [Here is that solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154572/how-to-make-this-tooltip-like-this-with-pure-javascript)

Here is the code:

```html
<script>
  function doTip(e) {
    var elem = e.toElement;
    if (elem.getAttribute('data-tip-on') === 'false') {

      elem.setAttribute('data-tip-on', 'true');
      var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
      var tipId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
      elem.setAttribute('data-tip-id', tipId);
      var tip = document.createElement("div");
      tip.setAttribute('id', tipId);
      tip.innerHTML = elem.getAttribute('data-tip');
      tip.style.top = event.clientY + 15 + 'px';
      tip.style.left = event.clientX + 10 + 'px';
      tip.setAttribute('class', 'tip-box');
      document.body.appendChild(tip);

    } else {

      elem.setAttribute('data-tip-on', 'false');
      var tip = document.getElementById(elem.getAttribute('data-tip-id'));
      tip.parentNode.removeChild(tip);


    }
  }

  function enableTips() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('quick-tip');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      elems[0].addEventListener("click", doTip, false);

    }
  }
  window.onload = function() {
    enableTips();
  }

</script>
<style>
  .quick-tip {
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-left: 350px;
  }

  .tip-box {
    /* change dimensions to be whatever the background image is */
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
  }

</style>

<map>
  <area class="quick-tip" shape="poly" data-tip="THIS IS THE TIP! change elements 'data-tip' to change." data-tip-on="false"/>

  <area class="quick-tip" shape="poly" data-tip="THIS IS THE TIP! change elements 'data-tip' to change." data-tip-on="false"/>
</map>

<script>
  enableTips();

</script>
```

Only the top one works, the bottom does nothing. The functionality I need is for both buttons to display the tool tip on click. I've tried stitching other parts of different solutions in to no avail. I've tried other solutions as well and none seem to work on my page.

I have modified the original solution and am using `<area>` because the page originally had tool tips pop up when hovering over the `<area>`. The hover functionality needs to be changed to click as in the solution, but the first one is the only one that ever works.

Comment: `elems[0].addEventListener("click", doTip, false);` should be `elems[i].addEventListener("click", doTip, false);`, otherwise it just adds two listeners to the first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo

```
elems[0].addEventListener("click", doTip, false);
```

should be

```
elems[i].addEventListener("click", doTip, false);
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you.